# Multer image upload patch request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

I have a code to upload a form with some field name & a single image in nodejs using multer. Everything works fine when a new file is being uploaded on the `POST` request. Also, the PATCH request for changing the image is working fine. But, the issue goes that if I need to only change the image, not the `service_name`, it nullifies the field instead of retaining the previous name provided while a new POST was created.

**PATCH REQUEST**

```
    exports.editService = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { service_name } = req.body;

    const updates = {};

    if (req.body) {
        updates.service_name = service_name;
    }

    if (req.file) {
        const service_pic = req.file.filename;
        updates.service_pic = service_pic;
    }

    try {
        const updated_data = await Services.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, {
            $set: updates
        },
            {
                new: true
            }
        );
        if (!updated_data) {
            res.status(404).json({ message: "Data does not exist" });
            return;
        }
        res.status(200).json({ message: "Data updated", result: updated_data });

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error", error });
    }
}
```

In the PATCH/PUT request, the `service_name` is always `null`.

Postman result:

```
{
    "message": "Data updated",
    "result": {
        "_id": "5f3648f8aefb2978e8f82d94",
        "service_name": null,
        "service_pic": "service_pic-1597396108999TIME-CLOCK-service.png",
        "createdAt": "2020-08-14T08:19:04.013Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-14T09:08:29.012Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

Not sure where I am handling it wrong. Any help to rectify this is appreciated.

Comment: What is in the `req.body`?

Comment: @gypsyCoder It's `req.body.service_name`

Comment: This sounds like a MongoDB issue

Comment: Try `updateOne` instead of `findOneAndUpdate`. Also, make sure the ID is an instance of `ObjectID`

Comment: @Daniel_Knights It's still the same.

Comment: What do you get if you console log `service_name`?

Comment: If I pass some new text for field `service_name`, it updates the document with that. But If no new text is passed for the `service_name`, it returns `undefined` in console. Which is expected, but then, it should retain the previous text value passed to `service_name` but instead turns it into `null` in the database.

Comment: You need to check for `service_name` instead of `req.body` in that `if` statement. Should fix it

Comment: @Daniel_Knights It worked.Thanks ! Can you elaborate the reason for this?

Comment: No problem, if `req.body` comes through empty, it still evaluates to `true`. So, `updates.service_name` is being set a value when there isn't one to set